# Android XML image in the full width

Tags: android, xml, layout, width

I have a problem with my xml file, i would like that background_bar take the full screen width (on the top of the screen) but I can't do that.. Please help me
Here is my code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

 <RelativeLayout
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/main_background_bar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/background_bar"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/main_logo_bar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/logo_bar" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/main_title_bar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="27dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/main_logo_bar"
        android:src="@drawable/notifme_title_bar" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Depending on what your `background_bar` image looks like, I would try to make a 9-patch out of it. That's the only way you can account for all screen sizes without potentially creating scaling artifacts.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `android:scaleType="fitXY"` or one of its variations to the background_bar.

Comment: as well as android:adjustViewBounds="true", I think